# django template get foreign key of queryset

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I have these models in my django app:

```
class GeoBonus(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
country = models.ForeignKey(Country, related_name='geo_bonuses')
bookmaker = models.ForeignKey(Bookmaker, related_name='geo_bonuses')
```

Attributes in Country and Bookmaker are not that important, lets say that each has `name` parameter.
In template I am having a for cycle:

```
{% for bookmaker in bookmakers %}
    {{bookmaker.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

and I want to print `name` of GeoBonus based on `country`. Lets say user's country is a string.

```
{% for bookmaker in bookmakers %}
    {{bookmaker.name}}
    {% if country_code %}
        {% for geo_bonus in bookmaker.geo_bonuses|in_country:country_code %}
            {{geo_bonus}}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is my filter:

```
@register.filter
def in_country(qs, country_code):
    return qs.filter(country__twocode=country_code)
```

Where `country_code` is send through view:

```
context = RequestContext(request,{
        'bookmakers': Bookmaker.objects.select_related('geo_bonuses').all(),
        'country_code': country_code,
    })
```

But this does not work. What am I doing wrong? I am getting `Invalid filter: 'in_country'` (if I use simple filter as `upper` for string, it works, so template tags are loaded).

So basicly my question is, **How to select one foreign key while running a for cycle**?

Comment: You didn't import your `in_country` into your template. You need to use `{% load file_that_defined_in_country %}` to load the filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has nothing at all to do with foreign keys or querysets. The error tells you exactly what is going wrong: it is not recognising the "in_country" filter.

Your assertion that "template tags are loaded" because `upper` works does not follow at all: `upper` is a built-in filter provided by Django itself, whereas `in_country` is not. You need to load your template tag library with `{% load module_that_defines_filter %}` before you can use it.

Comment: you are right. However I do have {% name_of_file %} in my template and folder does contain `__init__.py` file, that is weird.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You need to actually call `load`.

Comment: I did call load. However I did another stupid mistake. I had file with same name in my another app. That was the problem. Thanks for your help!